# NLS_LANG setting for JDBC thin driver?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, nls, ora-12705

I am using the thin Oracle JDBC driver ver 10.2.0 (ojdbc14.jar). I would like to configure its NLS_LANG setting manually. Is there a way?

Currently it fetches this setting from the VM variable user.language (which is set automatically by setting the current locale, or on startup from the system environment).

This is a problem when the users switch the application locale to a one that is unsupported by the Oracle JDBC driver (e.g. mk_MK). In this case, the next time I fetch a connection I get the following exception:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
```

I can change the locale on the fly just before I fetch the connection and switch back to the user's selected one back and forth, but this seems unelegant and unefficient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The NLS_LANG settings are derived from the java.util.Locale . Therefore, you will need to make a call similar to this before connecting:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.<your locale here>);
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did end up doing. It works fine, but it is not very pretty. Thanks!

Comment: God Tier answer. Use `Locale.US` to mimic the `AMERICAN` language settings.

Answer (score 20):

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/63216/ora-12705-cannot-access-nls-data-files-or-invalid-environment-specified/64536

For me the best response was by FoxyBOA to invoke java app with:

```
-Duser.country=en -Duser.language=en
```

Comment: Funny. Vote for own answer cross-posted here :D

Comment: +1 as it's a lot less invasive than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for SQLDeveloper and also for web-logic data-source

Comment: This one solved my problem:  -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US

Answer (score 11):

I was fighting the same problem and found out that thin jdbc Oracle drivers do not require NLS_LANG or system locale to be specified. But when you connect to non-english databases you are to have orai18n.jar in the classpath.

from **Oracle® Database JDBC Developer’s Guide and Reference**

> **Providing Globalization Support**
>
> The basic Java Archive (JAR) files,
>   ojdbc5.jar and ojdbc6.jar, contain all
>   the  necessary classes to provide
>   complete globalization support for:
>
> - Oracle character sets for CHAR,
>     VARCHAR, LONGVARCHAR, or CLOB data
>     that is not  being retrieved or
>     inserted as a data member of an Oracle
>     object or collection type.
> - CHAR or
>     VARCHAR data members of object and
>     collection for the character sets 
>     US7ASCII, WE8DEC, WE8ISO8859P1,
>     WE8MSWIN1252, and UTF8.
>
> To use any other character sets in
>   CHAR or VARCHAR data members of
>   objects or  collections, you must
>   include orai18n.jar in the CLASSPATH 
>   environment variable   of your
>   application.

Answer (score 7):

Invoking java with the following works for me :

```
-Duser.country=us -Duser.language=en
```

if "en" for country also causes [ORA-12705](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12705_error.htm).

Comment: That is because there is no "EN" country. There are: US, GB, and many others that have English as official language

Answer (score 1):

You should use the old Oracle 9.2 JDBC driver that is fully compatible and certified with Oracle 10g. The old driver does not use ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE commands.