# Adding data source for jidea 11.0.2

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, intellij-idea

i'm trying to connect to a oracle 10g database from inside jidea,i'm using ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar as the jdbc driver. attached is the error message i'm getting when 
i'm trying to connect! can any one help me to solve this issue??

```
Connection to oracle - albi1dv1 failed
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:388)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:381)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:564)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:431)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:359)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
```

Regards,
Rangana

Comment: This post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/1629327/778687

Comment: thank you for the quick comment! this will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

i have used the jdbc driver named ojdbc14_noneXe.jar, it solved my problem. :)

FYI - i'm connecting to a remote oracle development database, not an local installation on my mechine!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone to IDEA. This will prevent this error.
Add the next line to file idea.vmoptions :

```
-Duser.timezone=your_database_timezone
```

Here's some explanation on [how to get your database timezone](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=484463)

Answer (score 0):

1. in eclipse go **run** - > **run configuration**
2. in there go to **JRE** tab in right side panels
3. in **VM Arguments** section paste this

   `-Duser.timezone=GMT`
4. then Apply - > Run