# Can't connect to Oracle database with SQL Developer (Ora00604 error occurred at recursive level 1 ORA - 12705)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11g Express Edition from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index-083047.html and also installed SQL Developer, but when I try connect to Oracle Database from Developer (I try create new connection) next error appears:

> Ora00604 error occurred at recursive level 1 ORA - 12705.

What should I enter at: Hostname, port and SID

TNSNAMES provided below:

```
XE = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DYedilkhan-ПК)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
```

Comment: XE for sid, 1521 for port, and localhost for hostname will probably work. I talk a little bit about this [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/30-sql-developer-tips-in-30-days-day-5-connectivity-issues/). Don't forget to check out your listener status.

Comment: It appears you may have a problem in your NLS_LANG setting - that's what the ORA-12705 is trying to tell you. For help resolving this see [this page](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12705_resolution.htm) and [this page](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12705_error.htm). Best of luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00604 ORA-12705](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629327/ora-00604-ora-12705)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux regarding [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363712/sylvain-leroux): un seul _p_ à _developer_ en anglais. ;)

Answer (score 22):

Add this rows into ..\sqldeveloper\ide\bin\ide.conf file

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
AddVMOption -Duser.region=us
```

It's working for me.

Comment: hurray for this answer and hurray for stack overflow! thanks macloving

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you don't know what language and region to use, you can add
AddVMOption -Duser.region=

(nothing after =)

It worked in my case as macloving solution did too

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing system language. In my case the problem occurred because Windows decided to change my "display language" to English(Kenyan), and unsurprisingly it wasn't supported by the Database.