# Oracle JDBC Exception Message Language is German

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am getting exception messages from Oracle through JDBC in German.  How can I change that to english?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Die Zeitzone f³r die Datenbank-Session ist nicht festgelegt
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.TimestampltzAccessor.getString(TimestampltzAccessor.java:94)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTimestampltzAccessor.getString(T4CTimestampltzAccessor.java:256)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:971)
```

Comment: would probably help if you could supply the NLS language set of the database and any clients you are using to access the database

Comment: @Kevinsky: I'm going to have to research that. I am not really sure where that is specified in my JDBC client.  As for the server, it is on the other side of the planet managed by people who don't answer my emails.  Getting the NLS language set of the server will take significantly longer.  (I was hoping this was something I could solve on the client side alone.)

Comment: on the database try select DECODE(parameter, 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'CHARACTER SET',
'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'LANGUAGE',
'NLS_TERRITORY', 'TERRITORY') name,
value from v$nls_parameters
WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY');           and on client from SQL PLUS SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;

Comment: @Kevinsky:  Thanks for your help.  Actually the host where the application in question runs does not have an Oracle client installation.  It is using the pure JDBC drivers for Oracle.  It turns out I have to set the default locale for the JVM with a call similar to this `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);` in order to get english exception messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for NLS settings it will be client side. see this like [NLS_LANG setting for JDBC thin driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079985/nls-lang-setting-for-jdbc-thin-driver) for how to set on the JDBC side.

Comment: The solution in the linked answer worked.  Specifically for me it was `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);`.