# ORA-01722: invalid number (Only For MacOS PC)

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, macos, testcontainers

The entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "policy_restriction_bound",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"policy_restriction_id", "upperBound", "currency"},
        name = "uq_policy_restriction_bound_restr_id_bound_currency"))
public class PolicyRestrictionBoundEntity {
    public static final int UPPER_BOUND_SCALE = 5;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence-generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence-generator", sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence", allocationSize = 5)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "policy_restriction_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_policy_restr_bound2policy_restr"))
    private PolicyRestrictionEntity policyRestriction;

    @NotNull
    private Integer minimumApprovesCount;

    @Positive
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private BigDecimal upperBound;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 3)
    private String currency;
}
```

Container

```
private static final OracleContainer DB_CONTAINER = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:18.4.0-slim-faststart");
```

The following is being inserted into Oracle db

```
protected List<String> getInsertTestDataAfterMigrationCommands() {
        return List.of("""
            """
                INSERT into policy_restriction_bound(id, policy_restriction_id, minimum_approves_count, upper_bound, currency)
                VALUES ('1', '1', '2', '99.99000', 'USD')"""
        );
    }
```

The error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number
Caused by: Error : 1722, Position : 134, Sql = INSERT into policy_restriction_bound(id, policy_restriction_id, minimum_approves_count, upper_bound, currency)
VALUES ('1', '1', '2', '99.99000', 'USD'), OriginalSql = INSERT into policy_restriction_bound(id, policy_restriction_id, minimum_approves_count, upper_bound, currency)
VALUES ('1', '1', '2', '99.99000', 'USD'), Error Msg = ORA-01722: invalid number

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:637)
```

Hello,

I am inserting the data via `getInsertTestDataAfterMigrationCommands()` method as above.
But I get `ORA-01722: invalid number` error.
When I delete the single quotes in `'`99.99000`'` the error goes away.
But what I'm wondering about is that we only get this error for all Macbook users in the team. This does not error occur on Linux and Windows PCs that also pass the Jenkins Pipeline.

Also when I delete Single quotes again pass the Jenkins Pipeline.
It is also interesting that we only receive single quotes issues with a `BigDecimal` value. No problem with other fields.

I couldn't find the reason why we only get this error on Macbook PCs, do you have any ideas?

Additional: I noticed that smart quotes on the Macbook were turned on. I disabled it, but we continue to get the error.

Comment: Not sure about your specific client issues, but in general numeric values in Oracle `insert` statements should *not* be quoted.

Comment: Yes I agree but I am still curious why it happens only in Mac PC's and BigDecimal

Comment: If you put quotes on numeric value, then an auto-conversion should happen somewhere between your app and oracle or oracle and macOS. So one thing it can be that oracle driver for mac is more explicit during conversion

Comment: @SveKamenska It is internal to the database. The OP's query is passed to the database and parsed by the SQL engine and the implicit cast occurs there and relies on the session parameters of the user's database session to control the expected format of the number.

Comment: @MT0, thanks for the detailed explanation - this is what I meant by the 2nd assumption - oracle <-> os interaction

Comment: It isn't the OS per-se.  The OS has nothing to do with what is being sent over the database connection.  It will be the JDBC driver or the application itself.   And I expect that it is JDBC driver version specific behavior rather than special JDBC driver behavior for MacOS.  (The latter would be perverse ... IMO.)  The drivers are supplied by Oracle or a 3rd party, not by Apple.

Comment: @StephenC The driver should just pass the query (and any bind parameters) to the SQL engine of the database and the database will parse the query and perform any implicit casts between data-types using its settings. What may have an impact is if the driver is being initialised with an `NLS_LANG` setting or if the `NLS_TERRITORY` or the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` session parameters are being set in the user's database session (otherwise the database defaults will be used); that is probably all that is going to have any impact here.

Comment: Good point.  But that's the application (or the application's config) setting those.  Not the OS.

Comment: @StephenC I've updated my answer with some options where a JDBC driver can derive the session parameters it uses in its connections. When the driver is loaded, it *may* take some settings from the OS to initialise the session parameters in the database session or those can be overridden by application settings or explicitly by directly setting the session parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary: **NEVER** rely on implicit string-to-number conversions. If you want to pass a numeric value then pass it as a number and **NOT** as a string.

---

When you insert a string into a `NUMBER` column then you are asking Oracle to perform an implicit string-to-number conversion and if the decimal separator is not `.` then `'99.99000'` will give the error:

```sql
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

(In Oracle 23, the error is more informative: `ORA-01722: unable to convert string value containing '.' to a number:`.)

You can see this if you change your session parameters:

```sql
CREATE TABLE policy_restriction_bound(
  id                     NUMBER(8,0),
  policy_restriction_id  NUMBER(8,0),
  minimum_approves_count NUMBER(8,0),
  upper_bound            NUMBER(10,5),
  currency               VARCHAR2(3)
);
```

Then:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
INSERT into policy_restriction_bound(id, policy_restriction_id, minimum_approves_count, upper_bound, currency)
VALUES ('1', '1', '2', '99.99000', 'USD');
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-01722: invalid number
> ```

and:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
INSERT into policy_restriction_bound(id, policy_restriction_id, minimum_approves_count, upper_bound, currency)
VALUES ('1', '1', '2', '99.99000', 'USD');
```

Works.

---

What you should do is **NEVER** rely on implicit string-to-number conversions. If you want to pass a numeric value then pass it as a number and **NOT** as a string.

If you must pass strings (don't) then make sure that all your test containers are using the same session parameters as the production database so that the behaviour is identical.

Depending on the JDBC driver, this could be by:

1. The connection's default session parameters which may be derived from the [language of the OS](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-nls-lang.html) or an `NLS_LANG` environment variable set in the OS.
2. Running the Java application and [explicitly specifying the language and locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4224705/1509264) when you start Java:

   ```console
   -Duser.country=en -Duser.language=en
   ```

   Which may cause the JDBC driver to override any default database settings and set the `NLS_LANG` and `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameters (which will set a the default `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` session parameter for that territory).
3. [Setting a locale in the Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306042/1509264):

   ```java
   Locale.setDefault(Locale.<your locale here>);
   ```

   Which may cause the JDBC driver to override any default database settings and set the `NLS_TERRITORY` (and maybe `NLS_LANG`) session parameter (which will set a the default `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` session parameter for that territory).
4. In SQL from the Java application, explicitly setting the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting in the database session (which will implicitly set the default `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` for that territory) and override any default settings for the connection.

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET TERRITORY = 'United States'
   ```
5. In SQL from the Java application, explicitly setting the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` session parameter (again, overriding the defaults).

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'
   ```

But it is much better to **NEVER** rely on implicit conversions.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v7kwFV7R)

Comment: @MTO I appreciate for details answers. The answer helped a lot to cover the subject.