The same java code does not work for all JDK
I have a code:
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public void call() {


    String input = "<ROOT>" +
                       "<START_DATE>20240824</START_DATE>" +
                    "</ROOT>";

    StoredProcedureQuery proc = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("procedureName");
    proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inXml", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("outXml", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("error", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

    proc.setParameter("inXml", input);

    proc.execute();

    var outXml = (String) proc.getOutputParameterValue("outXml");
    var error = (String) proc.getOutputParameterValue("error");

    log.info(outXml);
    log.info(error);

}

This is a Spring Boot ( version 3.0.7 ) application.
I call stored procedure on Oracle db with date as a parameter.
I run the code on two computers:
1. java installed =  openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)
2. java installed = openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
Number 1 works fine but in number 2  the error comes up = ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
Could you tell me why the same code does not work on server number 2 ?

Maybe you could share a stacktrace of the exception?

Did you try your code in the SQL client?

Yes, the code in Oracle SQL developer works fine

the error is from procedure that the date format is incorrect, but this is the same string from both apps

Then you should post a procedure code with the line of the error.

Please provide the actual code that fails, not just the one calling it.

I do not have the source code of the stored procedure that I call, because it is from an external company

The programs are connecting to the same server but two connections each start a different session and those sessions have (for some reason) got different NLS session parameters.
Somewhere in your procedure you are performing an implicit conversion from a string to a DATE:

In the first session, the NLS_DATE_FORMAT matches YYYYMMDD and the implicit conversion succeeds.
In the second session, the NLS_DATE_FORMAT does not match YYYYMMDD and the implicit conversion fails with the error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.

The solution is to NEVER rely on implicit conversions.
You do not provide the source code for your procedure but if you use TO_DATE(value), change it to use an explicit format model TO_DATE(value, 'YYYYMMDD'). Similarly if you are relying on implicit conversions in XML functions - don't rely on the implicit conversion; make it explicit.

An alternative solution is create a logon trigger so that at the start of every session you run:
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD';

To set the format model that Oracle uses for implicit string-to-date (and vice versa) conversions. However, this is not best practice and you should fix your code not to rely on implicit conversions.

I do not have the source code of the stored procedure that I call, because it is from an external company, so its is possible to solve the problem considering that i cannot modify stored procedure on Oracle ?

The server number 2 is located in different country than country where oracle procedure is executed. It can be a reason that NLS session parametres not match ?

@newuser123123 You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1079985/1509264 because the Oracle JDBC driver is probably deriving the NLS settings from the locale (which means you would get different NLS settings in different territories of the world). Alternatively, as mentioned in the answer, look at running ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD' once after you create a connection to the server (you could do it as a logon trigger but if you don't have control of the server then you could run it manually).

MT0 , thank you for your help, you understood my problem perfectly. The problem is solved now.
